# I am not getting a number as output but instead a emoji

Tags: c++

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptazI.png)I wrote C++ program which asks the user for two numbers and operator and gives the output based on the input.I think everything is correct but the output is not the desired output.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1;
    string op;
    int num2;
    string result;

    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter a operator: ";
    cin >> op;
    cout << "Enter another number: ";
    cin >> num2;

    if (op == "+"){  //if user types '+' the result is num1 + num2
        result = num1 + num2;
        //cout << result;
    }else if (op == "-"){ //if user types '-' the result is num1 - num2
        result = num1 - num2;
       // cout << result;
    }else if (op == "*"){ //if user types '*' the result is num1 * num2
        result = num1 * num2;
        //cout << result;
    }else if (op == "/"){ //if user types '/' the result is num1 / num2
        result = num1 / num2;
        //cout << result;
    }else{
        cout << "Invalid operator...";
    }
    cout << result;



    return 0;
}
```

The output should be integer.But the output is just a diamond.

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and compile (using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org)...) with `g++ -Wall -g`

Answer (score 4):

Declare the variable result as having the type int

```
int result = 0;
```

Or maybe it is even better to declare it as

```
long long int result = 0;
```

and use it like

```
result = static_cast<long long int>( num1 ) * num2;
```

In your program it has the type `std::string`

```
string result;
```

Comment: Of course, since the OP is using division, it may be useful to use a `double` or `float` instead to store the result. But that would obviously be up to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a integer value to a string so I think so it is converting that integer value to character value and giving that emojis. My case was same as your, I
was assigning integer value to a string. But I then declared that integer value as a character value and it worked fine then.

Also the best approach is to use to_string() function to change the integer value to a character value.